# Write XML-RPC in C# and using it from Python

Tags: c#, python

I have a C# XML-RPC code and I want to use it from Python, is there a capability to 
implement that?

this is my code
 in C#
  1- dll file

```
public class Search:MarshalByRefObject
 {
     public string GetAllFiles()
     {
         return ("hhhhhhiiiiiiiiiii");
     }

 }
```

2- to register method

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(new TcpChannel(6600));
            RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(
            Type.GetType("Search,Search"), "MySearchServer", WellKnownObjectMode.SingleCall);
        }
```

in python

```
 s = ServerProxy('http://localhost:6600')  
  print(s.GetAllFiles())
```

when I execute it, I get the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "D:\RemotingF\rpc1.py", line 17,
>   in Listen
>       print(s.GetAllFiles())   File "C:\Python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line
>   1224, in **call**
>       return self._*send(self.*_name, args)   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line
>   1570, in _*request
>       verbose=self.*_verbose   File "C:\Python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line
>   1264, in request
>       return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line
>   1297, in single_request
>       return self.parse_response(response)   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line
>   1462, in parse_response
>       p.feed(data)   File "C:\Python27\lib\xmlrpclib.py", line
>   557, in feed
>       self._parser.Parse(data, 0) xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not
>   well-formed (invalid token): line 1,
>   column 4

anyone help me
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your C# code is indeed **XML-RPC** server, not remoting ? From the Python error it seems that the server's response is not a valid XML.